# MongoDB failed (result: core-dump)?

Tags: mongodb

I'm attempting to setup MongoDB on Ubuntu 20.04.02 LTS by following the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#install-mongodb-community-edition). I have ensured this is a fresh install. However an error persists when I verify if the MongoDB install started succesfully by typing in:

```
sudo systemctl status mongod

> ● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
>      Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor prese>
>      Active: **failed (Result: core-dump)** since Wed 2021-08-11 12:59:20 UTC; 49s >
>        Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
>     Process: 3190 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=dum>    Main PID: 3190 (code=dumped, signal=ILL)
> 
> Aug 11 12:59:19 discorddomagoj systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database
> Server. Aug 11 12:59:20 discorddomagoj systemd[1]: mongod.service:
> Main process exited,> Aug 11 12:59:20 discorddomagoj systemd[1]:
> mongod.service: Failed with result '>
```

Comment: You should provide the content of `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`

Comment: make sure you have these folders and file `/var/lib/mongodb`, `/var/log/mongodb` and `/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock` with ownership of `mongodb`

Answer (score 0):

Though the `mongod` logs would provide more info, from the logs shown it appears from `signal=ILL` that the `mongod` binary wasn't compiled for the platform you are running it on. This message indicates an illegal instruction. See [MongoDB's production notes](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/administration/production-notes/) for more on supported CPUs and platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened on my end when installing the mongodb current 7.00 version on ubuntu 22.04 using virtual box.
Issue Tittle as "mongodb illegal instruction (core dumped)".
I have tried many ways. But the problem was not resloved at all.
And finally i find out the solution.

Solution:

1. Just Uninstall the virtual box and then download and install the vmware.
2. Now install the ubuntu 22.04 inside your vmware machine
3. Then install the mongodb 7.0v

Or You may just follow the full process to resolve core-dump issue on mongodb by the following link...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8XdK6wN_XVQ&ab_channel=ArtTVGallery

Thanks.